# Atajos de Teclado En VS Code

Tags: windows, vscode, keyboard, atajo

Soy nuevo en VS Code y cuando quiero escribir una combinación de teclas convencional de Windows para escribir un carácter especial, me encuentro con que por ejemplo, al presionar ALT + 164, que es equivalente a la "ñ", me abre un menú de "Source Control" que no es lo que quiero.

¿Cómo puedo utilizar estos atajos en VS Code?

Saludos

Comment: Tienes la tecla numlocks activada?

Comment: Sí, está activada

Answer (score 0):

Actualizando mi propia pregunta, el problema se debía a una extensión que había instalado, IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings.

La desinstalé y asunto arreglado, ahora me funcionan los atajos de teclado por defecto de Windows.